# SQL field value of 0 returns empty

Tags: php, sql

I have variable types of data in my SQL database, and I am poplulating a table with PHP.

Sometimes I have 3 columns, sometimes I have more, depending on the type of data.
If I use:

```
    $fourthcolumn=$row['fourth'];
    if(empty($fourthcolumn)){
    // DO NOTHING
    }else{
    echo "<td class='fourth'>" . $fourthcolumn. "</td>";
    }
```

Then it works as expected with one exception:
Some columns are quantities. When the quantity is '0', it is returning as empty and does not make the td with a value of '0'.

In my structure, if there is no info, then the cell is completely blank, and that is what i would expect to come back as empty

Is there any way to return the '0'? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`empty(0)` evaluates to true in php

[see manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues)

so you could check explicitly

```
if(empty($fourthcolumn) && $fourthcolumn !==0 && $fourthcolumn !== "0"){
// DO NOTHING
}else{
echo "<td class='fourth'>" . $fourthcolumn. "</td>";
}
```

Comment: That should most likely need to be `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The answer was based on the positive result being handled in the else condition as in the question. Edited to be clear

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think either would work though. OP hasn't responded to any answers/comments yet; only time will tell ;)

Answer (score 1):

The php document for empty() defines how it functions as "Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

0 would be considered false.

I would suggest using instead

```
$fourthcolumn=$row['fourth'];
if(isset($fourthcolumn)){
    echo "<td class='fourth'>" . $fourthcolumn. "</td>";
}else{
    // DO NOTHING
}
```

isset checks if a variable is not null.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: This way of thinking makes more sense to me, however I am setting the variable in case it has data, so it is always set. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
$fourthcolumn=$row['fourth'] ?: 0;
```

It describe like this

if `$row['fourth']` is null then 0

Comment: I need to do different things to 0 and null, they are not the same in my structure. I need to display 0, and not display null. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: i mean if it null then it will return a 0 value, you can try it

Answer (score 0):

> bool empty ( mixed $var )
>
> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

In PHP, 0 == false.  So empty (correctly) returns true if the value it is checking is 0.

The problem could be solved as follows:

```
if(empty($fourthcolumn) && $fourthcolumn !== 0 && $fourthcolumn !== "0"){
// DO NOTHING
}else{
```

Where you check to make sure the $fourthcolumn is not equal to the number 0 or the string "0" (using strict equality, so it won't match for false, or an empty string, for example).

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. I saw andrew's post first though, and it wont let me mark both as correct answers. Thanks!